# Why do vfat partitions have a special GUID/UUID format in GUID Partition Tables?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, uuid, guid, vfat

According to the Wikipedia article on the [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), the partition GUID's reside in the Partition entries (LBA 2-33) just after the Primary GPT Header at the beginning of the volume. As such, the GUID/UUID values are not stored inside the partitions themselves but in the partition table, and so one would think they should a priori be independent of the filesystem types of the partitions.

However, when I look at my fstab file, I have the two following lines:

```
UUID=9a260e1b-f1eb-4cec-9273-f5743539805c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=D8BD-647A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

where the UUID for the /boot/efi partition of type vfat is of a different format than the UUID generally encountered.

How comes a different format is used for vfat partitions? How comes the *partition* GUID/UUID format depends on the *filesystem type* of the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UUID=` tags **are not** partition IDs. They're filesystem IDs. Nearly all filesystems have an unique ID in their header, independent from the partition table – and in your example, ext4 just happens to use the same "128-bit UUID" format, but it is still an ext4-specific ID. (NTFS has 64-bit IDs, LVM and ZFS have...)

For GPT partition table GUIDs, you're looking for the **`PARTUUID=`** tag instead.

```
lsblk -o name,fstype,uuid,label,partuuid,partlabel
```

Comment: I see. Do you know if there are "filesystem type UUIDs/GUIDs" (same as there are "partition type GUIDs")?

Comment: No, there's no such thing... the filesystem type usually has to be detected based on individual knowledge of each filesystem's "magic numbers" (see e.g. how libblkid in util-linux does it).